# Find all postive integer numbers $x,y$,such $x+y+1$ divides $2xy$ and $x+y-1$ divides $x^2+y^2-1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all postive integer $x$ and $y$ such that
$x+y+1$ divides $2xy$ and $x+y-1$ divides $x^2+y^2-1$

My try: since
$$(x+y)^2-2xy=x^2+y^2$$

I know this well know reslut:
$$xy|(x^2+y^2+1),\Longrightarrow \dfrac{x^2+y^2+1}{xy}=3,x,y\in N$$
and such condition $$(x,y)=(u_{n},u_{n+1})$$
where
$$u_{0}=u_{1}=1,u_{n+2}=3u_{n+1}-u_{n}$$
so I can't,Thank you

Comment: 3 divides 6 and 4 divides 16 but 7 does not divide 22.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that 
$\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=x^2+y^2-1+2xy\quad * $

Use the above expression to prove that $x+y-1$ divides $2xy$ and $x+y+1$ divides $x^2+y^2-1$

Note that $x+y-1$ and $x+y+1$ have the same parity.

Let both of them be odd, then they are coprime

$\implies \left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)$  divides each of $2xy$ and $x^2+y^2-1$
Let the quotient of the division be $a$ and $b$ respectively. Use $*$ to arrive at $a+b=1$

> $$a\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=2xy$$ and $$b\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=x^2+y^2-1$$ adding both of them gives $\left(a+b\right)\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=x^2+y^2-1+2xy=\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)$ as we are speaking of $2xy$... being divided by $x+y+1$ or $x+y-1$ and as we don't say is divisible by zero, we can neglect the case in which $\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=0$. Which yields the condition $a+b=1$

let both of them be even.

$\implies \frac{\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)}{2}$ divides each of $2xy$ and $x^2+y^2-1$ . Let the quotient of the division be $c$ and $d$ respectively. Use $*$ to arrive at $c+d=2$.

> $$c\frac{\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)}{2}=2xy$$ and $$d\frac{\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)}{2}=x^2+y^2-1$$ adding both of them gives $\left(a+b\right)\frac{\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)}{2}=x^2+y^2-1+2xy=\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)$ as we are speaking of $2xy$... being divided by $x+y+1$ or $x+y-1$ and as we don't say is divisible by zero, we can neglect the case in which $\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)=0$. Which yields the condition $a+b=2$

Since $a,b,c$ and $d$ are positive integers, there cannot exist a case in which $a+b=1$. And $c=d=1$. This causes either of $x+y-1$ or $x+y+1$ zero which is absurd as we are talking about division.

For the second case we have $x^2+y^2-1=2xy=\frac{\left(x+y+1\right)\left(x+y-1\right)}{2}$
Which gives $\left(x-y\right)^2=1$ $\implies x=y+1$ or $x=y-1$

Comment: Your proof doesn't work.

Comment: @TimRatigan. Why do you say so?. Have you seen any error?.

Comment: @TimRatigan, I have added a line "Use the above expression to prove that $x+y-1$ divides $2xy$ and $x+y+1$ divides $x^2+y^2-1$"

Comment: @TimRatigan I started proving that both can only have same parity. Say if one of them is odd, then the another is also odd. So these two odd numbers which differ by two are coprime. Since the $x+y+1$ divides $2xy$ and $x+y-1$ divides $2xy$ and because both $x+y+1$ and $x+y-1$ are coprime then only $(x+y+1)(x+y-1)$ divides $2xy$. And for the second case, in which both are odd, as 2 is the HCF of these numbers you can only say $\frac{(x+y+1)(x+y-1)}{2}$ divides $2xy$. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Oh, I see where the problem is.  You immediately dismiss $c=d=1$, which is actually possible.  $$x^2+y^2-1=2xy\implies (x-y)^2=1$$

Sorry if I've been a bit aggressive here, I was trying to figure out why our proofs didn't match up.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since $(x+y+1)(x+y-1)=(x^2+y^2-1)+2xy$,
$$
x+y-1\mid x^2+y^2-1\iff x+y-1\mid2xy\tag{1}
$$
Since
$$
x+y+1\mid2xy\tag{2}
$$
and $(x+y-1,x+y+1)\mid2$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply
$$
(x+y)^2-1\mid4xy\tag{3}
$$
However, because $4xy\le(x+y)^2$, $(3)$ implies $(x+y)^2-1=4xy$, that is,
$$
(x-y)^2=1\tag{4}
$$
Wlog, assume $y=x+1$, then
$$
x+y-1=2x\mid2x(x+1)=2xy\tag{5}
$$
and
$$
x+y+1=2(x+1)\mid2x(x+1)=2xy\tag{6}
$$
Thus, the solutions are $\{(x,y):(x-y)^2=1\}$

Comment: Your answer always very nice!+1

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+y+1)(x+y-1)-1(x^2+y^2-1)=2xy$$

If we assume $x\equiv y\pmod 2$, then $\text{lcm}(x+y+1,x+y-1)=(x+y)^2-1$ since the expressions are coprime.  If $x+y-1\mid x^2+y^2-1$, the above equality would imply that $x+y-1\mid 2xy$, but since $2xy<(x+y)^2-1$ ($x,y>0$), this implies $x+y+1\not \mid 2xy$.

If $x\not\equiv y\pmod2$, then $\text{lcm}(x+y+1,x+y-1)=\frac{(x+y)^2-1}2$.  In order to construct a similar argument to before, we need $$\begin{align} \frac{(x+y)^2-1}{2}&>2xy\\
(x+y)^2-1&>4xy\\
(x+y)^2-4xy&>1\\
(x-y)^2&>1\\
|x-y|&>1 \end{align}$$

This leaves us with two cases: $x=y$ and $x=y+1$.  We can dismiss the first since it implies $x\equiv y\pmod 2$.  So we want $$(y+1)+y-1=2y\mid (y+1)^2+y^2-1=2y^2+2y$$ Which is true.

We also need $$(y+1)+y+1=2y+2\mid 2(y+1)y$$ Which is true for all $y$.

---

In conclusion, your solution set for the problem is $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2\mid |x-y|=1\}$